# Array to select multiple sheets to unhide

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on code to unhide selected columns in multiple sheets and
with values in "Command" sheet cell B5:

[image: Sheet]

Each column in row 4 has a value (JAN, FEB, MAR, ...). What I need is to unhide all columns in the selected sheets below that match the values in B5.

My sheets names are: `ADB_Name`, `TDB_Name`, `TPD_Name`.

My code:

```
Sub Unhide_CI()

Dim cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("ABB_Name","TDB_Name","TPD_Name")
    For Each cell In .Range("C4", .Range("XFD4").End(xlToLeft))cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.Value = Sheets("Command").Range("B5") And Not IsEmpty(cell)    
    Next cell    
End With     
Application.ScreenUpdating = True   

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, but your post is not clear. Can you post a screen-shot of your "Command" sheet, what cells are you trying to comapre with.

Comment: Hello Command Sheet attached

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub Unhide_CI()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sheetsNames As Variant, sheetName As Variant, refVal As Variant

    sheetsNames = Array("ABB_Name", "TDB_Name", "TPD_Name") '<--| list your sheets names here

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    refVal = Sheets("Command").Range("B5") '<--| retrieve your reference value only once outside the loop

    For Each sheetName In sheetsNames '<--| loop through sheets names array
        With Worksheets(sheetName) '<--| reference current sheet
            With .Range("C4", .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '<--| reference its row 4 cells from column 4 right to last not empty one
                .EntireColumn.Hidden = True '<--| hide all referenced columns
                For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through not empty referenced cells in row 4
                    cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = Not cell.Value = refVal '<--| unhide current cell column if it matches referenc value
                Next cell
            End With
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the tip.. the code say's "Subscript Out of Range"? what does it mean?

Comment: Make sure the worksheet names match up with the SheetNames array.